# Split String With Some Constraints In Java

Tags: java

I have a string like this :

```
12
```

I want to get split to `[2]` ignoring `1`. Is it possible to do so in java?

Comment: possible........

Comment: yes. what have you tried so far? Have a look at string functions.

Comment: I think you need a better example, or a set of them.  There are numerous ways to get the 2 out of the twelve, this example does not really show what you are tying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` method to split on a regex input or, better yet, if you know the exact position or character you want to split at (as seems to be the case here), just use `substring()` combined with `indexOf()`. Something like:

```
String substring = string.substring(0, indexOf("2"));
```

where `string` is your original String variable..

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact index,

```
String str = "12"
String s = str.substring(1,2);  // output 2
```

or

```
String s = str.substring(0, indexOf("2"));  //output 2
```

or

```
char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
char c = chars[1]; // output
```